# Highcharts temperature legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a highstock chart with multiple axises. I would like to be able to show a legend displaying the difference in temperature in different colors as shown in the example here on the right[image]

At the same time, I need to show a new series with a specific temperature, a temperature color on a specific date as shown on the top of the chart.

Does anyone have a suggestion to have this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us working example what have you done till this moment? I think that heat map is good idea for your temperature colours.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using [heatmap.js](http://code.highcharts.com/) module of Highcharts.

Please check this two examples:

- [Temperature variation by day and hour](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/)
- [Heatmap density](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap)

What you are trying to do is something the combination of these two examples. You can also use the `plotOptions.heatmap` [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.heatmap) to learn which functions and options you can use in Highcharts heatmaps.